# What is the correct way to register FluentValidation with Simple Injector?

Tags: dependency-injection, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0, open-generics, simple-injector

I am able to register FluentValidation `AbstractValidators` using a `FluentValidatorFactory`. However, it doesn't *feel* right, because not all of the IoC container registrations happen during bootstrap / composition root. Instead, the [fluent validators are registered by a separate factory](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ValidatorFactory&referringTitle=Documentation):

The **composition root**:

```
public class SimpleDependencyInjector : IServiceProvider
{
    public readonly Container Container;

    public SimpleDependencyInjector()
    {
        Container = Bootstrap();
    }

    internal Container Bootstrap()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register< // ...register all non-fluent-validator types, then

        container.Verify();
        return container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return ((IServiceProvider)Container).GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

An **abstract fluent validator factory** depending only on IServiceProvider

```
public abstract class FluentValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private IServiceProvider Injector { get; set; }

    protected FluentValidatorFactory(IServiceProvider injector)
    {
        Injector = injector;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return Injector.GetService(validatorType) as IValidator;
    }
}
```

A **fluent validator factory implementation** for SimpleInjector

```
public class SimpleValidatorFactory : FluentValidatorFactory
{
    public SimpleValidatorFactory(SimpleDependencyInjector injector) 
        : base(injector)
    {
        var validators = AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        validators.ForEach(validator => 
            injector.Container.Register(
                validator.InterfaceType, validator.ValidatorType));
        injector.Container.Verify();
    }
}
```

SimpleInjector has good support for open generics, and all of my fluent validator classes have signatures similar to the following:

```
public class SomeClassValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeClass>
{
    public SomeClassValidator([depedencies injected here])
    {
        // ... set up validation rules
    }
}
```

So, is there a better way to register the validators in the bootstrap / composition root, instead of using fluent's validator factory?

P.S. @DotNetJunkie -- would be great if you had [a wiki page on this at simpleinjector.codeplex.com](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: Why have you wrapped the container inside an `SimpleDependencyInjector` abstraction? That seems redundant.

Comment: A wiki page about Fluent Validation would be too framework specific. There are hundreds of frameworks that could have a wiki page; were to stop?

Comment: @Steven, the `SimpleDependencyInjector` class is for a simpleinjector-specific implementation of IServiceProvider. I don't want any references to the SI container, just as I didn't have code that referenced IUnityContainer before switching to SI.

Comment: @Steven, you are right about the wiki. In fact, you already have a wiki that basically explains exactly what I was asking for. I just had to read it a couple of times before it clicked: http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios&referringTitle=Documentation#Registration_Of_Open_Generic_Types

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I figured this out myself.

1.) Register fluent's open generic `IValidator<T>` interface in the composition root:

```
public class SimpleDependencyInjector : IServiceProvider
{
    public readonly Container Container;

    public SimpleDependencyInjector()
    {
        Container = Bootstrap();
    }

    internal Container Bootstrap()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        // some container registrations

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
        container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);

        // some more registrations

        container.Verify();
        return container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return ((IServiceProvider)Container).GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

2.) Get rid of the `SimpleValidatorFactory` class.

3.) Make the `FluentValidatorFactory` a non-abstract, concrete class:

```
public class FluentValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private IServiceProvider Injector { get; set; }

    public FluentValidatorFactory(IServiceProvider injector)
    {
        Injector = injector;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return Injector.GetService(validatorType) as IValidator;
    }
}
```

4.) Register the FluentValidatorFactory as the validation factory provider in global.asax:

```
var injector = new SimpleDependencyInjector();
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(
    provider =>
    {
        provider.ValidatorFactory = new FluentValidatorFactory(injector);
    }
);
```