# AbstractValidator classes are always singletons despite being registered as transient

Tags: c#, asp.net, simple-injector, fluentvalidation

I'm using SimpleInjector 4 and FluentValidation 7. My `AbstractValidator`s have a dependency on my `DbContext`.

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<LocationModel>
{
    public LocationModelValidator(IReadOnlyRepository repository)
    {
        // Check the database to see if this location is already present
        RuleFor(x => x.LocationId).Must(x => !repository.Location.Any(i => i.LocationId == x)).WithMessage("A Location with this ID already exists.");
    }
}
```

My composition root looks as follows:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

container.Register<IReadOnlyRepository, LocationDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IValidatorFactory>(() => new ServiceProviderValidatorFactory(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies, Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

container.Verify();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

ValidatorFactory implementation

```
public class ServiceProviderValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _config;

    public ServiceProviderValidatorFactory(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return (IValidator) _config.DependencyResolver.GetService(validatorType);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
// throws error: instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope
// FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, x => x.ValidatorFactory = container.GetInstance<IValidatorFactory>());

FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config, x => x.ValidatorFactory = new ServiceProviderValidatorFactory(config));
```

The validation kicks in and works fine for the first API request but all subsequent API requests give the `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` error.

I've also tried setting up `ServiceProviderValidatorFactory` to use `IServiceProvider` approach and calling `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config, x => x.ValidatorFactory = new ServiceProviderValidatorFactory(container));`

as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43883455/654708

but that doesn't work either.

It looks as though once the `AbstractValidator`s have loaded, they are cached/never disposed of but the `DbContext` is. 
I'm guessing a hybrid lifestyle might work here (as setting the `IReadOnlyRepository` to a singleton lifestyle works fine) but I haven't had any luck there either.

**UPDATE**

Looks as though the `AbstractValidator` classes are Singletons. I've updated the validators and factory to be transient in the composition root but it doesn't seem to work as they are still only getting instantiated once.

```
container.Register<IValidatorFactory>(() => new ServiceProviderValidatorFactory(container), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies, Lifestyle.Transient);
```

I've verified this by setting a break point inside one my `AbstractValidator` classes and can see that it only gets called once, i.e. on the first web api request but not on subsequent requests.

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to somewhat get around this problem by inject a `Func<IReadOnlyRepository> repository` into my `AbstractValidator` classes:

```
public class LocationModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LocationModel>
{
    public LocationModelValidator(Func<IReadOnlyRepository> repository)
    {
        // Check the database to see if this location is already present
        RuleFor(x => x.LocationId).Must(x => !repository.Invoke().Locations.Any(i => i.LocationId == x)).WithMessage("A Location with this ID already exists.");
    }
}
```

And updating my composition root with the following:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<IReadOnlyRepository>>(() => container.GetInstance<IReadOnlyRepository>);
```

I'd rather not have to do this but given I can't figure out why the `AbstractValidator`s are always singletons, it will do for now.